# Issue in PHP accessing an object's method

Tags: php, oop, oauth, twitter

Not completely new to PHP itself, but new to using OOP w/ PHP.

Object instantiation & calling method exist in different file.

**index.php has this:**

```
<?php
require_once 'scripts/twitteroauth/oauth_index.php';
?>
```

**oauth_index.php has this:**

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
```

**and the file submitting the tweet, submitMessage.php contains this:**

```
include 'twitteroauth/oauth_index.php';

$message = $_GET['message'];
$time = $_GET['time'];

$status = "#" . $message . $time; 

$twitter->updateStatus($status);
$output = $twitter->updateStatus($status);
```

**Have tested:**
The form submits successfully & gets to the PHP file. The updateStatus() method works fine ***if it is used within index.php***. However, when I submit the form, it is passed to a js function, which passes the variables to the submitMessage.php, and then responds with all the text after $twitter->. It responds *"updateStatus($status);$output = $twitter->updateStatus($status);"*

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

**entirety of sendMessage.php**

```
<?

include 'twitteroauth/oauth_index.php';

$message = $_GET['message'];
$time = $_GET['time'];

$status = "#" . $message . $time; 

$output = $twitter->updateStatus($status);
$twitterReturn = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: You submit to a .js page? Unless you're running node.js, that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, I put it the wrong way, I call a function defined in a separate .js file, I am not passing values to a .js file.

Comment: Assuming `submitMessage.php` starts with `<?php`, and you're echoing `$output` as brenjt suggests, have you tried using Firebug to check what the actual response from the server is? (I assume you're using an Ajax call as you mention a .js file.) Are you just putting the response into a page and assume that's all that's being returned because that's all you can see on the page?

Comment: Daren, the response, according to firebug, is the entirety of the php file.

Comment: Daren, yeah... had <? instead of <?php. Thanks for pointing that out. Putting a post-it note on my forehead - KISS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the `$output`;

Comment: I don't understand what this will fix? The problem is that right after 'twitter->' it outputs the rest of the php file as text.

Comment: I see what you're saying. That'll help it actually work once the bug is ironed out :P